# Manipulating Data to find the Greater Than Value

Tags: vba, excel

I need to sort data in a workbook that contains several sheets with just one macro, so far I have managed to record the steps that I need to remove the unnecessary information but then am having a problem when I have to specify different greater amounts.

I need the macro to be able to do the following:

1. Message box to prompt for the greater
   than amount to be specified
2. Highlight the values that are greater than specified

Current Code:

```
Sub Conditional_Formatting()
    Columns("J:J").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("GULP USD").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("GULP USD").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("J1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("GULP USD").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
        Formula1:="=250000"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

Unfortunately the data sheets contain various different lines of data and will require various greater than amounts per sheet so will need to have a way to run this without specifying a certain number of rows or a specific greater than value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Jean-FrançoisCorbett i have amended the post to only include the section of the code that i am stuck on, namly the "greater than" and "Highlight" section

Comment: How is any of the code posted related to your question? Delete all that, then try something that actually addresses your question. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

Comment: Your code so far relies on information being provided in **exactly** the right cells. Whatever solution you come up with using absolute references is probably going to be extremely brittle and maintenance intensive.

Comment: See <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195768(v=office.11).aspx" title="InputBox">InputBox</a>  Also, you don't need the `range.select` and then `selection.dosomething` statements.  I know that's how the macro recorder shows it, but `Range(address)` and `Selection` are both `Range` objects - so you have the same methods and properties available to each.  You can just call `Range("A1").Copy` instead of having to select the object first.

Comment: What's up with links today?  Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195768(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Thanks @CBRF23 excuse my very limited knowlege of VBA only been doing this for the past few weeks.  I seem to be getting an error on the code    Range("B2").Copy    Range("A2").Paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your new post, one available solution to the first question (messagebox to prompt for the greater than value) would be to use the `InputBox` function.

You can create a string variable and populate it with the return from inputbox.

i.e.

```
Dim strReturn           As String
strReturn = InputBox(Title:="Greater than what??", Prompt:="Enter a numeric value and I'll highlight everything greater than it for you.", Default:="42")
```

Then you can pass that to a numeric data type using the appropriate change function.

i.e.

```
Dim lngGreater          As Long
lngGreater = CLng(strReturn)
```

As far as your code goes, here is what I did with it:
Note:  I don't know what your autofilter is supposed to do.  I just added something in my code when testing, so you can change the `ELSE` portion of the `IF` block to setup your autofilter as you need it if it's not on.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Conditional_Formatting()

Dim rngColumns      As Excel.Range
Dim wshGULP         As Excel.Worksheet
Dim strGreater      As String
Dim lngReturn       As Long

'First things first, lets ask our user for a greater than value
    strGreater = InputBox(Title:="Greater than what??", prompt:="Enter a numeric value and I'll highlight everything greater than it for you.", Default:="42")

'I'm assuming you want numeric values, but if not we can change this next part. I did just as an example for you.
'Basically, we are going to check if the user entered _
 a numeric value, and if not - we're going to ask them to retry or quit.

        If Not IsNumeric(strGreater) Then

        'Did you know the messagebox function returns something as well?  It returns a numeric value that indicates what button the user pressed.
            lngReturn = MsgBox(prompt:="I don't know what to do with non-numeric numbers. Please enter a numeric value, or press cancel to quit.", Title:="What was that??", Buttons:=vbOKCancel)

        'Now, we can recursively call this routine to try again, or we can quit based on whatever the user's choice was.
                If Not lngReturn = vbCancel Then Conditional_Formatting
            Exit Sub
        End If

'If execution gets this far, we know we have a numeric value for our greater than condition and we can move on.

'It's easier to set an object once, especially if you want to change your code later, so lets just set the worksheet here
    Set wshGULP = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("GULP USD")


    'Another timesaver is to use a "With" statement.  Basically, you tell the VBA compiler that eveyrthing you want to do applies _
     to the object that is the target of the "With" statement.  You stop this "With" block with the "End With" statement
        With wshGULP

        'Instead of using Columns("J:J").Select, you can just assing that range to a Range object
            Set rngColumns = .Range("J:J")

            'Have to check if there IS an autofilter before we can clear it
                If Not .AutoFilter Is Nothing Then
                    .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
                Else
                    rngColumns.AutoFilter
                End If


        'Notice I changed the J1 absolute reference in the next line to be the first cell of our column range object - again, makes it easeier if you need to change things later
            .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(rngColumns.Cells(1, 1)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

            'You can nest With statements like so:
            'You probably noticed, but I like to use TAB to indent my code so it's easier to see the stucture visually...
                With .AutoFilter.Sort
                    .Header = xlYes
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                    .Apply
                End With

        'Now we're back into the original "With" block - remember, it stays in effect until you reach the "End With" statement for that block
        End With

    'I assume you want to select cells before calling this procedure, and have any in the selection highlighted, so I left this pretty much as you had it. _
     Just showing the same nested "With" blocks concept again for another example
        With Selection
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:="=" & strGreater    'See - this is where we set the greater than value you entered at the beginning
            .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
                With .FormatConditions(1)
                        With .Interior
                            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                            .TintAndShade = 0
                        End With
                    .StopIfTrue = False
                End With
        End With

End Sub
```